# PCLinuxOS - Failed to start the X server

Tags: nvidia, x-server, segmentation-fault

I am trying to install PCLinuxOS on a msi laptop with Nvidia Geforce GT650M

I have tried install direct from USB and from Live CD.

In all cases after reboot I get the error message Failed to start the X Server.

I have tried altering the grub command by removing `splash quiet` and replacing with `nomodeset` but still the same issue.

Looking in the log, I see a segmentation fault at 0x0

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://www.pclinuxoshelp.com/index.php/Testing_and_bug_reporting).

Comment: There is no option to register. It has been disabled and replaced with a message to send an email enclosing your required username & password. LOL security is obviously not high on agenda, but I have done so anyway and will see if I get any response.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the issue. I found an answer to another similar question, although different problem. It suggested to delete xorg.conf file and reboot. I did this and it now works. Not sure if any of the other changes I made during setup also helped but below are the changes I made

- Don't probe foreign OS
- On the last setup page (grub conf) I went into advanced options and unchecked all four options.